# Not a valid directory error when the directory exists

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I am constantly getting the following error:

`AssertionError: /Food-101/images/train is not a valid directory.`

`Food-101` is in the same directory as the notebook.  They're the children of the same parent directory.  This is the absolute directory:

`/home/user/Projects/food-101/Food-101, notebook`

Comment: you are probably confusing absolute and relative paths https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Food-101/images/train`. The first slash means the path is not relative, but absolute.